# How to unset an environment variable from docker?

Tags: docker

I want to unset the environment variable through entry point scripts.  I am sourcing the cleanup.sh in entry point script.

But the unsetting of the environment variable is not happening. There are no issues with the script when I exec to the container and run source cleanup.sh, the environment variable is unsetting

cleanup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
unset -v TEST_PASSWORD
```

source cleanup.sh in entrypoint.sh

Comment: Can you provide a syntactically correct [mcve]?  Why do you think the environment variable isn't getting unset?  `source` is a vendor extension that many shells don't support (e.g., the BusyBox `sh` in Alpine base images), consider the standard `.` command instead.

Comment: I tried both . command and source.  When I exec to the container, the environment variable values are showing unchanged.  The cleanup script is working when I run it manually, but not through the entrypoint script

Comment: If you `docker exec` into a container, that process isn't a child of the entrypoint and won't inherit any environment variables the entrypoint sets or unsets.  Don't worry about that; the main container process will be affected.  (Usually you want to reserve `docker exec` for debugging tasks if the main container process is acting up and it's not the primary way you interact with a container.)